# Release used memory after closing a form

Tags: c#, winforms, dispose

I have ribbon form that contain DevExpress Tabbed View.
[image]
When I start the program in the task manager, I am getting **118.6 MB** of used memory
Now when I open new form **"FrmWeldingProduction"** on Tabbed View
[image]
I get these results (Used Memory) when I open and close form **"FrmWeldingProduction"**
First open 274.4 MB       First close 272.1 MB
Second open 403.9 MB      Second close 401.6 MB
Third open 564.9 MB       Third close 562.2 MB
This is the code behind the form

```
public partial class FrmWeldingProduction : XtraForm, IDisposable
{
    readonly CLS_Welding welding = new();
    readonly CLS_User us = new();
    private RepOptionsFirstLastTime firstLastTime = new();
    private readonly CultureInfo cultureInfo = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
    private readonly string WeldingProduction = Application.StartupPath + "\\WeldingProduction.xml";
    private readonly string LayoutWeldingProduction = "LayoutWeldingProduction";
    private readonly int IDScreen = 19;
    public FrmWeldingProduction() { InitializeComponent(); }

    private async Task Permission()
    {
        using(DataTable Dt = await us.ApplayPermission(Program.UserID, IDScreen).ConfigureAwait(true))
        {
            if(Dt.Rows[0][1].ToString() == "False" || string.IsNullOrEmpty(Dt.Rows[0][1].ToString()))
            {
                repItemCreationDate.ReadOnly = true;
            }
            if(Dt.Rows[0][2].ToString() == "False" || string.IsNullOrEmpty(Dt.Rows[0][2].ToString()))
            {
                btnDelete.Enabled = false;
                btnDeleteNoir.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
    }

    private void FrmWeldingProduction_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        workspaceManager1.CaptureWorkspace(LayoutWeldingProduction, true);
        workspaceManager1.SaveWorkspace(LayoutWeldingProduction, WeldingProduction, true);
        DisposeFrm();
    }

    public void DisposeFrm()
    {
        us.Dispose();
        firstLastTime.Dispose();
        this.Load -= FrmWeldingProduction_Load;
        gridView1.FocusedRowChanged -= gridView1_FocusedRowChanged;
        repItemCreationDate.DrawItem -= RepItemCreationDate_DrawItem;
        btnRefresh.Click -= btnRefresh_Click;
        this.KeyDown -= FrmWeldingProduction_KeyDown;
        btnProductionProject.ItemClick -= btnProductionProject_ItemClick;
        gridView1.CellValueChanged -= GridView1_CellValueChanged;
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    private async void gridView1_FocusedRowChanged(
        object sender,
        DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.FocusedRowChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.FocusedRowHandle > 0)
        {
            using(DataTable EmployeeWeldingByProduction = await welding.GetEmployeeWeldingByProduction(
                Convert.ToInt32(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, "FK_ShiftTime"), cultureInfo),
                Convert.ToDateTime(
                    gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, "Date de fabrication"),
                    cultureInfo)
                    .ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", cultureInfo),
                Convert.ToInt32(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, "FK_idPartShip"), cultureInfo),
                Convert.ToInt32(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, "OrderNumber"), cultureInfo))
                .ConfigureAwait(true))
            {
                gridControl2.DataSource = EmployeeWeldingByProduction;
            }
        }
    }

    private async void btnRefresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using(DataTable WeldingProduction = await welding.GetWeldingProduction().ConfigureAwait(true))
        {
            gridControl1.DataSource = WeldingProduction;
        }

        using(DataTable WeldingPaintProduction = await welding.GetWeldingPaintProduction().ConfigureAwait(true))
        {
            gridControl3.DataSource = WeldingPaintProduction;
        }
        using(DataTable WeldingPaintFabRest = await welding.GetWeldingPaintFabRest().ConfigureAwait(true))
        {
            gridControl4.DataSource = WeldingPaintFabRest;
        }
        using(DataTable WeldingPaintStatusCHProject = await welding.GetWeldingPaintStatusCHProject()
            .ConfigureAwait(true))
        {
            gridControl5.DataSource = WeldingPaintStatusCHProject;
        }
        using(DataTable ProductionCharpent = await welding.GetProductionCharpent().ConfigureAwait(true))
        {
            gridControl6.DataSource = ProductionCharpent;
        }
        using(DataTable StatusSupportsBS = await welding.GetStatusSupportsBS().ConfigureAwait(true))
        {
            gridControl7.DataSource = StatusSupportsBS;
        }


        if(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle > 0)
        {
            using(DataTable EmployeeWeldingByProduction = await welding.GetEmployeeWeldingByProduction(
                Convert.ToInt32(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, "FK_ShiftTime"), cultureInfo),
                Convert.ToDateTime(
                    gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, "Date de fabrication"),
                    cultureInfo)
                    .ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", cultureInfo),
                Convert.ToInt32(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, "FK_idPartShip"), cultureInfo),
                Convert.ToInt32(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, "OrderNumber"), cultureInfo))
                .ConfigureAwait(true))
            {
                gridControl2.DataSource = EmployeeWeldingByProduction;
            }
        }
    }

    private async void FrmWeldingProduction_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        KeyPreview = true;
        btnRefresh_Click(sender, e);

        foreach(GridColumn columnDateEdit in gridView1.Columns)
            columnDateEdit.OptionsColumn.AllowEdit = false;
        gridView1.Columns["Date de fabrication"].OptionsColumn.AllowEdit = true;

        //pivotGridControl1.DataSource = await welding.GetProductionCharpent().ConfigureAwait(true);


        workspaceManager1.TargetControl = this;
        workspaceManager1.SaveTargetControlSettings = true;
        if(workspaceManager1.LoadWorkspace(LayoutWeldingProduction, WeldingProduction, true))
            workspaceManager1.ApplyWorkspace(LayoutWeldingProduction);

        await Permission().ConfigureAwait(true);
    }

    private bool IsHoliday(DateTime dt)
    {
        //the specified date is a Holiday
        if(dt.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Friday)
            return true;
        //New Year's Day
        if(dt.Day == 1 && dt.Month == 1)
            return true;
        //Independence Day
        if(dt.Day == 5 && dt.Month == 7)
            return true;
        //VAlgerian War of Independence
        if(dt.Day == 1 && dt.Month == 11)
            return true;
        //Employees Day
        if(dt.Day == 1 && dt.Month == 5)
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    private void RepItemCreationDate_DrawItem(
        object sender,
        DevExpress.XtraEditors.Calendar.CustomDrawDayNumberCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.View != DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.DateEditCalendarViewType.MonthInfo)
            return;
        //return if a given date is not a holiday
        //in this case the default drawing will be performed (e.Handled is false)
        if(!IsHoliday(e.Date))
            return;
        //highlight the selected and hot-tracked dates
        bool isHotTracked = e.State == DevExpress.Utils.Drawing.ObjectState.Hot;
        if(e.Selected || isHotTracked)
        {
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(e.Style.GetBackBrush(e.Cache), e.Bounds);
        }
        //the brush for painting days
        Brush brush = (e.Inactive ? Brushes.LightPink : Brushes.Red);
        //specify formatting attributes for drawing text
        using(StringFormat strFormat = new StringFormat
        {
            Alignment = StringAlignment.Center,
            LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center
        })
        {
            //draw the day number
            e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Date.Day.ToString(), e.Style.Font, brush, e.Bounds, strFormat);
        }
        //no default drawing is required
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    private void FrmWeldingProduction_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if(e.KeyCode == Keys.F5)
            {
                btnRefresh_Click(sender, e);
            }
        } catch
        {
        }
    }
    private void btnProductionProject_ItemClick(object sender, DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        if(firstLastTime == null || firstLastTime.IsDisposed)
            firstLastTime = new RepOptionsFirstLastTime();
        firstLastTime.Show();
        firstLastTime.OK.Click += ProductionProject_Click;
    }

    private async void ProductionProject_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using(RepWeldingProductionSumm report = new())
        {
            // Create a new parameter. 
            Parameter param1 = new();
            Parameter param2 = new();
            Parameter param3 = new();
            // Specify required properties. 
            param1.Name = "FirstDatepara1";
            param1.Type = typeof(DateTime);
            param1.Visible = false;
            param1.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(firstLastTime.FirstDate.EditValue, cultureInfo)
                .ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", cultureInfo);

            param2.Name = "lastDatepara2";
            param2.Type = typeof(DateTime);
            param2.Visible = false;
            param2.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(firstLastTime.LastDate.EditValue, cultureInfo)
                .ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", cultureInfo);


            param3.Name = "shifttime";
            param3.Type = typeof(string);
            param3.Visible = false;
            param3.Value = firstLastTime.cmbShiftTime.Text;


            report.Parameters.Add(param1);
            report.Parameters.Add(param2);
            report.Parameters.Add(param3);
            if(firstLastTime.cmbShiftTime.Text == Resources.allDay ||
                string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstLastTime.cmbShiftTime.Text))
            {
                report.DataSource = await welding.RepWeldingProductionSumm(
                    Convert.ToDateTime(firstLastTime.FirstDate.EditValue, cultureInfo)
                        .ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", cultureInfo),
                    Convert.ToDateTime(firstLastTime.LastDate.EditValue, cultureInfo)
                        .ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", cultureInfo))
                    .ConfigureAwait(true);
                firstLastTime.Close();

                report.ShowRibbonPreviewDialog();
            } else
            {
                report.DataSource = await welding.RepWeldingProductionShiftTimeSumm(
                    Convert.ToDateTime(firstLastTime.FirstDate.EditValue, cultureInfo)
                        .ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", cultureInfo),
                    Convert.ToDateTime(firstLastTime.LastDate.EditValue, cultureInfo)
                        .ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", cultureInfo),
                    Convert.ToInt32(firstLastTime.cmbShiftTime.EditValue, cultureInfo))
                    .ConfigureAwait(true);
                firstLastTime.Close();
                report.ShowRibbonPreviewDialog();
            }
        }
    }

    private async void GridView1_CellValueChanged(
        object sender,
        DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.CellValueChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        await Permission().ConfigureAwait(true);
        if(e.Column.FieldName == "Date de fabrication")

        {
            await welding.UpdtaeCreationDateWeldingProduction(
                Convert.ToInt32(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle, "id"), cultureInfo),
                Convert.ToDateTime(e.Value))
                .ConfigureAwait(true);
            XtraMessageBox.Show(
                Resources.operationAccomplishedSuccessfully,
                Resources.Confirmation,
                MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get OOM after X open/close?

Comment: Use a memory profiler to check for leaks

Comment: Might also be worth debugging and stepping through the code to see at what point the bulk of the memory is being allocated.

Comment: Remove `Dispose(true);` and `GC.SuppressFinalize(this);` from your `DisposeFrm()`. Override `OnFomClosed` instead of subscribing to the event (?) and call `DisposeFrm()` after `base.OnFomClosed`. Dispose only of the object you have created that hold unmanaged resource (e.g., Graphics objects), those the Form doesn't know about. It doesn't look like you have added those event handlers in addition to others added in `InitializeComponent()`. -- (Unrelated) `.ConfigureAwait(true)` is the default, no need to specify that.

Comment: I don't see how you're assigning all those Graphics objects to your Controls. If those Graphics objects are assigned from Resources directly, in code (not in the Constructor), without assigning the Resource to a local object that you can dispose, you have a big problem.

Comment: I am really sorry for the late reply.  first of all, this is the first time i get to this problem. @Jimi I try to do what you said until now I managed to free up 10 MB.                          I am start using Memory Profiler, I'm trying to figure out how to use it.                                I'm open to any suggestions.